# Need help getting VOID code working w/ gross pay

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks, c++builder

I am in need of help correcting an error with the following code.Its primary function is to receive a users hours worked, then based on the logic behind the number of hours worked, apply the appropriate hourly rate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
void getGrossPay(int regular,
                 int &timeAndHalf,
                 int &doubleTime);

int main()
{   //variables
    const int REG_RATE = 10;
    const int TIME_HALF = 15;
    const int DOUB_TIME = 20;
    int hoursWorked = 0;

    cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): ";
    cin >> hoursWorked;
    getGrossPay(regular, timeAndHalf, doubleTime);

    while (hoursWorked != -1);
    {
        if(hoursWorked >=1 && hoursWorked <=37)
        {
        getGrossPay(regular);
        cout << "Your gross pay is: $ (press -1 to exit)" << regular << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): ";
        cin >> hoursWorked;
        }
        else
            if (hoursWorked >=38 && hoursWorked <=50)
        {
            getGrossPay(timeAndHalf);
            cout << "your gross pay is: $(press -1 to exit)" << timeAndHalf << endl;
            cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): ";
            cin >> hoursWorked;
        }
            else
            if (hoursWorked >=50)
            {
            getGrossPay(doubleTime);
            cout << "your gross pay is: $(press -1 to exit)" << doubleTime << endl;
            cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): ";
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            }//end if
    }//end while


}// end of main function


    //****function definitions*****
    void getGrossPay(int regular,
                 int &timeAndHalf,int &doubleTime)
    {
        regular = hoursWorked * REG_RATE;
        timeAndHalf = hoursWorked * TIME_HALF;
        doubleTime = hoursWorked * DOUB_TIME;

    } // end getGrossPay function
```

Yes, this is for a class. No, I dont want the answer.

Suspected issues:

- My void syntax is erroneously organized
- My while statement isnt properly utilized
- My variables are illegally being called from the void function

Any and all aid in putting me on the right track is 100% appreciated.

EDIT:

So this code "fix" gets me to an executable that freezes basically:

void getGrossPay(int regular,
                 int &timeAndHalf,
                 int &doubleTime);

```
const int REG_RATE = 10;
const int TIME_HALF = 15;
const int DOUB_TIME = 20;
int hoursWorked = 0;
int regular = 0;
int timeAndHalf = 0;
int doubleTime = 0;
```

int main()
{   //variables

```
cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): " << endl;
cin >> hoursWorked;

while (hoursWorked != -1);
{

    if(hoursWorked >=1 && hoursWorked <=37)
    {
    getGrossPay(regular, timeAndHalf, doubleTime);

    cout << "Your gross pay is: $ (press -1 to exit)" << regular << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): " << endl;

    cin >> hoursWorked;
    }
    else
        if (hoursWorked >=38 && hoursWorked <=50)
    {
        getGrossPay(regular, timeAndHalf, doubleTime);
        cout << "your gross pay is: $(press -1 to exit)" << timeAndHalf << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): " << endl;
        cin >> hoursWorked;
    }
        else
        if (hoursWorked >=50)
        {
        getGrossPay(regular, timeAndHalf, doubleTime);
        cout << "your gross pay is: $(press -1 to exit)" << doubleTime << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your hours worked(press -1 to quit): " << endl;
        cin >> hoursWorked;
        }//end if
}//end while
```

}// end of main function

```
//****function definitions*****
void getGrossPay(int regular,
             int &timeAndHalf,int &doubleTime)
{
    regular = hoursWorked * REG_RATE;
    timeAndHalf = hoursWorked * TIME_HALF;
    doubleTime = hoursWorked * DOUB_TIME;

} // end getGrossPay function
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: `REG_RATE`, `DOUB_TIME`, `TIME_HALF` are only declared __inside__ the `main()`function; they are unaccessible to `getGrossPay()`. See my answer below for other faults in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`getGrossPay()` is declared with 3 parameters by definition. However, at 3 instances in your `main()` function, such as:

```
getGrossPay(regular);
```

only **one** parameter is passed to your function. You need to re-work your function as the are many logic errors regarding `getGrossPay()` in your code.

In additon, you have not declared `regular` in `main()`, but you pass it to the `getGrossPay()` function.

***Also***, you have declared `DOUB_TIME`, `REG_RATE` and `TIME_HALF` **inside** your `main()` function; hence, it is unaccessible in the `getGrossPay()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If GetGrossPay is prototyped as a function with three parameters, it will not work without giving it three arguments. I suggest modifying your function.